# Make users recommend better places for a question

Tags: feature-request

Whenever a question "cannot" be answered because it is in the wrong part of stackexchange, it should be mandatory to recommend another forum to go to. So downvoting or closing a question is to require a reason. And if this reason is: "wrong place" then the user who downvoted or closed needs to choose from a list or insert a place himself the OP can go to.

Comment: No, that's not our job here has users.  We may sometimes suggest a alternate site, but we do not and should not have any obligation to do so.  The obligation is on the asker to post in the right place.

Comment: Although I think Mr. Grumpy could word it in a nicer way, most of these questions do not have a proper site, if there is a proper site I never go without a mod flag pointing there. This is not something that should be required as many off topic posts have no better home.

Comment: @Kortuk - I agree with [Grumpy](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mau0ekDZ7S1rtii2to2_500.jpg). I'm always prepared to suggest a better place if I know one, but if the question is about [weather balloons](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43409), I'm sorry, but I'm not going to search the 'Net for a forum where they discuss cameras in weather balloons. If OP wants to hire me as a consultant it would be a different story.

Comment: Never said I disagreed.saying that it does happen when possible. The community is very active about it.

Answer (score 2):

Posts can be flagged as "Off topic", and with the help of moderators they can be migrated to other sites of the StackExchange network. It usually also requires the approval of moderators of the destination site.

Comment: sometimes, when you push off topic, it recommends other sites, but on here it only recommends meta.electronics.  is there a way to add other sites to that list, like stack overflow, dsp.SE, and avp.SE?

Comment: @endolith there's a reason for that (Kortuk explained it to me). Looking at the statistics, we don't have significant abitual migration paths that may justify a menu entry. Therefore, you can write it in the generic flag box.

Comment: I don't understand how that's better

Comment: @endolith it's not better...simply the small amount of migrations doesn't justify the effort of creating a direct path

Comment: Approvation? "Approval," perhaps...

Comment: @JYelton right, thanks. At least the meaning was clear, I hope

Comment: @endolith if there is a suggestion then the community can migrate there themselves. Right now we dont have a major migration path so any migration requires review.

Answer (score 1):

Not every question will have an appropriate stack exchange site.  The Internet's a big place, so there's usually a forum somewhere for any quesiton, but I don't see why our users should be expected to know every forum for every question out there.

Even some on-topic questions are better asked at other forums.  Broad, open-ended questions are better at a threaded forum like http://askelectronics.reddit.com.  Software-tool-specific questions are usually better asked at the tool's own forums or mailing lists.

Comment: You see, without you mentioning that forum I would've been clueless. By such a comment I also found the piclist as a valueable resource for quick support.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to agree that an off-topic question should be closed or migrated *without* downvotes, if it is a reasonable, well-worded question. Down votes should not be used simply because the question is off topic. They are for marking questions as low quality in some fashion.

That said, if a question is off topic, I think it reasonable to provide the OP with some advice about more appropriate venues, if you know of one. Sometimes we run across questions for which we know of no appropriate forum, and at those times it should be acceptable to simply close the question as off topic, and let the OP do the research.

*"Sorry, you have the wrong number." and hang up. Simple.*

Comment: Downvoting is saying that the user poorly researched their question, by posting on the wrong site they have shown that they poorly researched their question.

Comment: Closing as off topic is simply saying *This is off topic here*.  Dowvoting and closing is saying *This is off topic here, which you should have known, moron*.  Both are sometimes appropriate messages to convey.

Comment: @Olin the moron part is not the word. Lazy maybe